# Want to adjust image sizes inside individual divs using jQuery, images are getting cut off

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on a tic tac toe game where the images representing the Xs and Os have to be visible. I was able to get the images to show, but they're too big and are cut off by the gridlines.

Here's the .js code:

```
          $('#box' + index).css(
            'background-image', "url('images/compass.png')");
      } else {
        choicesO.push(Number(index)) // pushing index into O
          checkForWins(choicesO);
          $('#box' + index).css('background-image', "url('images/dubloon.png')");
        }
```

I figured it's something about the height and the width, but I did this `'background-image', "url('images/compass.png')", 'height', '50');` and it didn't work. Then again, I'm very new to jQuery and I'm not sure if the syntax on that was even correct. Or if I was headed in the right direction.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: do a google search : https://www.google.com/search?q=responsive+background+image+css+jquery&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the css `background-size` property with the image sizes. More info [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Scaling_background_images)